# USB recognized, but not usable

Tags: usb, 14.04

I booted my computer today and I don't know what happened, but all my USB devices aren't working anymore (webcam, mouse, keyboard, external drive). I can see them being connected through `sudo lsusb`, but Ubuntu doesn't let me use them. How do I get them back?

`sudo lsusb`

```
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 05ac:129e Apple, Inc. Ipod Touch 4.Gen
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 046d:08f0 Logitech, Inc, QuickCam Messenger
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 016: ID 093a:2510 Pixart Imaging, Inc. Optical Mouse
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 009 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 008 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 007 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`dmesg`

```
usb 3-5: new low-speed USB device number 6 using ohci-pci
usb 3-5: New USB device found, idVendor=093a, idProduct=2510
usb 3-5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
usb 3-5: Product: USB OPTICAL MOUSE
usb 3-5: Manufacturer: PIXART
```

`lsmod`

```
Module Size Used by
pata_acpi    13038 0
pata_atiixp 13271 1
ahci 25819 0
libahci 32168 1 ahci
r8169 67581 0
mii 13934 1 r8169
```

`lsblk`

```
NAME MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda 8:0 0 232.9G 0 disk
   sda1 8:1 0 167.7G 0 part /
```

Comment: What does `dmesg` out when you put any of these device into USB slot. What does `lsmod` show?

Comment: @RuslanGerasimov This is what happens when I inserted my mouse. Other inserted devices are Iphone and webcam.

Comment: Post the output of `lsblk`

Comment: @Naveen `lsblk` added

Comment: What happened to the rest `65GB` space of your hard disk?? Is that the complete output of `lsblk`?

Comment: @Naveen I made two partitions when I installed Ubuntu, for if I ever wanted to dual boot. Never actually dual booted. It was my first time installing an OS myself. Yes that's the complete output. The `65G` is unused.

Comment: Your USB is not to be seen in `lsblk` wired!

Comment: @Naveen What does that mean? Should my USB be shown in `lsblk`? If so, what might have happened? :s